# jquery parent() issue

Tags: jquery, parent

**I speak English not well**, so i show my code and problem right now.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<td class="yyyy">
    <a id="delete" href="#" >Anchor</a>
</td>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("a#delete").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var s = $(this).parent("td").attr("class");
        alert(s);           
    });    
});
```

it returns a alert "undefined". I think it must be "yyyy".

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/NguyenThanh/WEaYw/4/

***I fixed my problem that i write fully html content of table (tr,td).
Thanks again!***

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="yyyy">
            <a id="delete" href="#" >Anchor</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    $("a#delete").click(function(e){
        var s = $(this).parent("td").attr("class");             
        alert(s);   
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: [No, it doesn't; it works perfectly well](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WEaYw/8/). I did, however, fix the HTML (a `td` is *only* valid within a `tr`, and the `tr` *must* be contained within a `table` (`tbody`, `thead` and `tfoot` are optional, however).

Comment: Then perhaps you should accept the answer that posted corrected HTML as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `<td>` like this as in your fiddle, It should be enclosed within `<table>` and `<tr>`:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="yyyy"> 
     <a id="delete" href="#">Anchor</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

try with this one:

```
    $("a#delete").click(function (e) {
       var s = $(this).parent("td").attr("class");
       alert(s);
       e.preventDefault();
    });
```

#### [Find in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WEaYw/17/)

Comment: +1 for thinking about the problem, rather than just suggesting an alternative jQuery method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var s = $(this).closest("td").attr("class");
    alert(s);           
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WEaYw/5/)

Comment: Why? Why do you advocate `closest()` when *it already works as written*?

Comment: Lets say we have nested `td` under that one more `td` under that `a` than it will take the class of the top level `td` which might not have any class. Also, we want class of `td` close to `a`

Comment: An `a` can't contain a `table`, so there'll be no `td` 'under' it. If there's another `td` containing the `table` (so nested `table`s), `parent()` would *still* work. I'm not criticising the use of `closest()` as such (I mostly prefer to use `closest()` rather than `parent()`), but `closest()` doesn't seem to address the problem the OP was facing.

Comment: Though I agree, `parent()` would also work for this example since it had a single `td` but incase we nested one, OP might wanna use `closest()`

Comment: tds should have parent tr and tr should have table. this is valid not just td

Comment: Yes, the issue here's that the HTML table markup was not correct simply.. and `closest()` is just a matter of preference. Both `closest()` & `parent()` would work here for the OP w/ valid `HTML table` markup.

Answer (score 2):

try to use   [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
   $(this).closest("td").attr("class");
```

Comment: And the reason you chose to use `closest()` when the jQuery works as written (given corrected HTML)?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var s = jQuery(this).closest("td").attr("class");
    alert(s);           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i made change in your code please check below jsfiddle link

:  http://jsfiddle.net/WEaYw/18/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="yyyy">
            <a id="delete" href="#" >Anchor</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

 jQuery(function($){
   $("a#delete").click(function(e){
      var s = $(this).parent("td").prop("class");

      alert(s); 
      e.preventDefault();   
   });
});
```